# Maximum Height Equals Maximum Width

Tags: html, css, image, sass, aspect-ratio

**Is there any way using only CSS to set a div's height to be never greater than its width?**

I have a series of images - portrait and landscape. I am currently containing them in a div set to 100% width with `top-padding` of `66.6666666%` which constrains the image to fit within this 1:1.5 ratio.

This is fine for landscapes, but for portraits, this means they can never be taller than the the landscapes are at 100% width, so the total area of portrait images is significantly less than landscapes.

If I set the container ratio to 1:1 (with a `top-padding` of `100%`), the portraits can achieve the same height as the landscapes are wide, however this means the landscapes have additional vertical space.

I'm looking for a way to constrain each image to a square area, without the extra space if it doesn't need it.

Comment: what browser support are you targetting?

Comment: @web-tiki Supporting IE9+

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired behavior with vw units :

> vw : 1/100th of the width of the viewport. (source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths))

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/tUcE8/)**

vw units are supported by IE9+ ([canIuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units))

*HTML :*

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-1200-600-6.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-h-g-600-1200-9.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    width:100%;
    max-height:100vw;
}
div > img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a height(or width) on the container of the image and by default the image should fit accordingly by using "background-size: contain" in your CSS.